# Cannot add Excel items to a database - it's giving a timeout error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble trying to upload Excel and send to my database. I've already debugged and it's giving problem in the line `dbocontext.BulkInsert(list)`.
I've tried anyway and I can't. But when adding just one item via form, it adds normally, now when I try this, it gives me the error.

Error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
> Operation canceled by user.
> The instruction has ended.'

My controller:

```
public IActionResult EnviarDados([FromForm] IFormFile ArquivoExcel)
{
    Stream stream = ArquivoExcel.OpenReadStream();

    IWorkbook MiExcel = null;

    if (Path.GetExtension(ArquivoExcel.FileName) == ".xlsx")
    {
        MiExcel = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
    }
    else
    {
        MiExcel = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);
    }

    ISheet HojaExcel = MiExcel.GetSheetAt(0);

    int cantidadFilas = HojaExcel.LastRowNum;
    int cantidadFilas2 = HojaExcel.PhysicalNumberOfRows;

    List<ProdutoDB> lista = new List<ProdutoDB>();
   
     for (int i = 1; i <= cantidadFilas; i++)
    {

        IRow fila = HojaExcel.GetRow(i);

        lista.Add(new ProdutoDB
        {
            Name = fila.GetCell(0).ToString(),
            Sku = fila.GetCell(1).ToString(),
            Active = fila.GetCell(2).ToString(),
            Description = fila.GetCell(3).ToString(),
            Price = fila.GetCell(4).ToString(),
            Qty = fila.GetCell(5).ToString(),
            Ean = fila.GetCell(6).ToString(),
            SkuManufacturer = fila.GetCell(7).ToString(),
            NetWeight = fila.GetCell(8).ToString(),
            GrossWeight = fila.GetCell(9).ToString(),
            Width = fila.GetCell(10).ToString(),
            Height = fila.GetCell(11).ToString(),
            Depth = fila.GetCell(12).ToString(),
            Guarantee = fila.GetCell(13).ToString(),
            Origin = fila.GetCell(14).ToString(),
            Unity = fila.GetCell(15).ToString(),
            Ncm = fila.GetCell(16).ToString(),
            Manufacturer = fila.GetCell(17).ToString(),
            ExtraOperatingTime = fila.GetCell(18).ToString(),
            Category = fila.GetCell(19).ToString(),
            Images = fila.GetCell(20).ToString(),
            Status = fila.GetCell(21).ToString()
        });
    }
    _dbocontext.BulkInsert(lista);
    //_dbocontext.Add(lista);


   return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new { mensaje = "Os dados foram carregados com sucesso!" });
}
```

Comment: How large is the list? You can either change the command timeout or insert the data in smaller chunks.

Comment: I'm doing the test with a list of only 1 item or 2 items. But it is giving this error.

Comment: All your input fields are strings, are the destination table fields also varchar?  Also, did you check the connection string?  How long did you wait before killing the task, if you let it run, would it run more than 3 minutes?

Comment: No database should timeout when adding 1-2 test items. What exactly is the timeout message? I assumed it was a command timeout, but it sounds more like a connection timeout attempting to connect to a server that cannot be reached.

Comment: I can only add one item if via form(mvc), but form is giving error "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Execution Timeout Expired. Timeout elapsed before completion of operation or server is not responding. Operation canceled by the user. The instruction has ended.'"

Comment: The connection is ok because I can also see the items that are in the DB. I didn't change the wait time.

Comment: help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Set SqlTimeout=0 this will run until your code excecute